# How do I use String methods on UTF-8 characters?

Tags: ruby

How do I use String methods on UTF-8 characters?

For example, I have a string with Cyrillic characters, so when I use `string.upcase` it doesn't work.

Comment: Please tell us if you're using 1.8 or 1.9, the behaviour changed significantly in 1.9 with regards to handling of encodings. In 1.8 strings were arrays of bytes, in 1.9 they are arrays of chars.

Answer (score 8):

Ruby only supports case conversions on the letters `A`–`Z` and `a`–`z`.

The reason for this is simply that case conversions for other letters aren't well defined. For example, in Turkish `'I'.downcase # => 'ı'` and `'i'.upcase # => 'İ'`, but in French `'I'.downcase # => 'i'` and `'i'.upcase # => 'I'`. Ruby would have to know not only the character encoding, but also the language to do that correctly.

Even worse, in German

```
'MASSE'.downcase
```

is *either*

```
'maße'   # "measurements"
'masse'  # "mass"
```

In other words: you need to actually *understand* the text, i.e. you need a full-blown AI, to do case conversions correctly.

And I myself have actually accidentally constructed a sentence once, which was undecidable *even for a human*.

In short: it's simply impossible to do correctly, which is why Ruby doesn't do it *at all*. There are third-party libraries, however, like the Unicode library and ActiveSupport, which *do* support a somewhat larger subset of characters.

Answer (score 7):

The rails [active_support](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support) gem has string extensions that can handle this.

For example:

```
# $ sudo gem install activesupport
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
'Laurent, où sont les tests ?'.mb_chars.upcase.to_s
# outputs => "LAURENT, OÙ SONT LES TESTS ?"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a cyrillic characters 
puts "ТОВА Е ТЕСТ".downcase => "ТОВА Е ТЕСТ"

Answer (score 0):

```rb
"ТЕКСТ".mb_chars.downcase # => "текст"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for downcase/upcase in Ruby 1.9, since the problems described in other posts. Still you can write you own gem, that will add support for cyrillic. You can look at my [gem for Polish](https://github.com/apohllo/string_pl) - turning on proper case folding is as easy as:

```
gem 'string_case_pl'
```

It also provides proper string sorting for Polish.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.4+ now supports more Unicode case mappings (`upcase` / `downcase`).

e.g.

> [String#downcase](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:downcase): "Full Unicode case mapping, suitable for most languages (see :turkic and :lithuanian options below for exceptions). Context-dependent case mapping as described in Table 3-14 of the Unicode standard is currently not supported."

Some details and use cases can be found [here](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/66-ruby-has-character.html#case-mapping).