# Capitalize the first character after a dash

Tags: ruby, regex

So I've got a string that's an improperly formatted name. Let's say, "Jean-paul Bertaud-alain".

I want to use a regex in Ruby to find the first character after every dash and make it uppercase. So, in this case, I want to apply a method that would yield: "Jean-Paul Bertaud-Alain".

Any help?

Comment: This could not be accomplished entirely by regex. Because matching can be done but converting to uppercase if job of programming language. But before moving ahead, have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 1):

`String#gsub` can take a block argument, so this is as simple as:

```
str = "Jean-paul Bertaud-alain"
str.gsub(/-[a-z]/) {|s| s.upcase }
# => "Jean-Paul Bertaud-Alain"
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
str.gsub(/-[a-z]/, &:upcase)
```

Note that the regular expression `/-[a-z]/` will only match letters in the `a-z` range, meaning it won't match e.g. `à`.  This is because `String#upcase` does not attempt to capitalize characters with diacritics anyway, because capitalization is language-dependent (e.g. `i` is capitalized differently in Turkish than in English). Read this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418681

Answer (score 0):

```
"Jean-paul Bertaud-alain".gsub(/(?<=-)\w/, &:upcase)
# => "Jean-Paul Bertaud-Alain"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the test more demanding by requiring the letter to be upcased: 1) be preceded by a capitalized word followed by a hypen and 2) be followed by lowercase letters followed by a word break.

```
r = /
    \b        # Match a word break
    [A-Z]     # Match an upper-case letter
    [a-z]+    # Match >= 1 lower-case letters
    \-        # Match hypen
    \K        # Forget everything matched so far
    [a-z]     # Match a lower-case letter
    (?=     # Begin a positive lookahead
      [a-z]+  # Match >= 1 lower-case letters
      \b      # Match a word break
    )         # End positive lookahead
    /x        # Free-spacing regex definition mode

"Jean-paul Bertaud-alain".gsub(r) { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "Jean-Paul Bertaud-Alain"

"Jean de-paul Bertaud-alainM".gsub(r) { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "Jean de-paul Bertaud-alainM"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

`.gsub(/(?<=-|\b)\p{L}/, &:upcase)`

which upcases any unicode letter following a word-break or dash, so this also works for non-ASCII characters:

```
"élaine-éclaire De-la rosa".gsub(/(?<=-|\b)\p{L}/, &:upcase)
=> "Élaine-Éclaire De-La Rosa"
```